# rails 3 form throws undefined method `model_name'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, models

userhome_controller:

```
  def edit_reviewer_email
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
```

edit_reviewer_email:

```
<div class="pagetop center">
    <%= form_for @user, update_reviewer_email_userhome_path(@user) do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :email %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :email, :size => 1 %>
        <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

error:

```
undefined method `stringify_keys' for "/userhome/18/update_reviewer_email":String
```

Should i be using form_tag when the model is accessed via a different controller?

I am looking for a rails 3 tutorial that covers a variety of forms if you know of any. 
Thanks!

Comment: Please post the full backtrace below the "undefined method" error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your controller needs to limit its request to a single record (you can just use `find`):

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

Or if you want to stick with a `where` statement:

```
@user = User.where("id = ?", params[:id]).first
```

Comment: When i change it to find vs where i get "Couldn't find all Users with IDs (id = ?, 18) (found 1 results, but was looking for 2)"

Comment: Can you update your question with the exact new code you tried and the exact error?

Comment: When you use `find`, you should just be passing in the `params[:id]` directly (like in my answer), not a `"id = ?", params[:id]` statement.

Comment: Also, Rails' `find(id)` approach already includes countermeasures to prevent against SQL injection.

Comment: learned two things. Thank you for the comments. Now i am getting another error. Updated above.

Comment: @DylanMarkow let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1468/discussion-between-jay-and-dylan-markow)